# .NET MVC Razorview form not showing using Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Main view:

Using an icon to make an ajax call to the AddAppForm action in the ApplicationController. It seems like my ajax call is successful .. but still don't see the form ... thoughts? Appears simple enough ... but ...

```
...
...
<div id="btn_add_app" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn_add_app" aria-hidden="true" style="color:forestgreen; cursor:pointer"></div>
...
...
$('.btn_add_app').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Application/AddAppForm',
            contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
    });
```

ApplicationController:
Return the form ...

```
[HttpGet]
// empty form
public ActionResult AddAppForm()
{
    Application app = new Application();
    app.name = "new name";
    return View(app);
}
```

View:

```
@model Project.Models.Application    

@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Add Application";
}

<h2>Add Application</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("saveApps", "Application"))
{
    <div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(a => a.name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.name)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(a => a.description)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.description)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(a => a.HIM)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.HIM)
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Because you not doing anything with the view you return from your `AddAppForm()` method. You need to update the DOM in the success callback - `$(someElement).html(result)` (and you can remove the pointless `contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',` option)

Comment: Your alert has the result in it, is it showing up?  If so then replace the alert with something as @StephenMuecke describes.

Comment: Also try returning a partial view result otherwise you will get your template returned too.

Comment: thanks! yes I see the whole template in the result ... tossed the return into a div and the form appears. For some reason, I assumed that if I am not returning server-side data it would render it ... #rookie

Answer (score 1):

## Your Ajax call is working

But you need to render the data received in some element on the screen:

```
<div id="renderDiv"></div>


[...]
success: function(data){
    $("#renderDiv").html(data);
}
```

Your whole View is inside the `data` variable, because of this you need to render

See more on the [JQuery .html() Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: yup, that's what I did ... and I have other divs in my main ... which I'd have to hide if I don't need em viewed. I am wondering if there is a better way to about this ...

Comment: If you want to hide multiple elements at once, you can place the same `class` on each one and hide then all: `$('.classToHide').hide()`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:

from

```
$('.btn_add_app').click(function () {
```

to

```
$('#btn_add_app').click(function () {
```

`.` sign means its calling a `class` and `#` means its calling an `id` this is the difference between the two.

and your URL:

From:

```
url: '/Application/AddAppForm',
```

to

```
url: "@Url.Action("AddAppForm", "Application")",
```

Your View doesn't have any relation to your ajax call because it calling an Action name called `saveApps` @using (Html.BeginForm("saveApps", "Application"))

and your Ajax url calling an action name of `AddAppForm`

You have to create an action name like

```
public ActionResult saveApps()
{

    return View();
}
```

To make your `@using (Html.BeginForm("saveApps", "Application"))` works.